# How much memory does it take to re-create a function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, memory-management

I'm a fan of a pattern that I guess we're all calling "Crockford Classless". The pattern works in all browsers and all environments, regardless of the available library, it allows strict mode to be defined in the function itself without having to re-define it all the time and offers the developer privacy in objects. It also removes the requirement of the `new` keyword as the function creates an instance whether `new` is used or not.

Here's a basic example of a `Person` "class" created using "Crockford Classless" and "psuedo-classical" to demonstrate the two styles:

```
// Pseudo-classical
var PersonA = function (details) {

    'use strict';

    this.firstname = details.firstname;
    this.lastname = details.lastname;

};

PersonA.prototype.getFullName = function () {

    'use strict';

    return this.firstname + ' ' + this.lastname;

};

// Creating an instance using Pseudo-classical
var person1 = new PersonA({firstname: 'John', lastname: 'Smith'}),
    person2 = new PersonA({firstname: 'Fred', lastname: 'Bloggs'});

person1.getFullName(); // -> "John Smith"
person2.getFullName(); // -> "Fred Bloggs"

// Crockford Classless
function PersonB(details) {

    'use strict';

    var firstname = details.firstname,
        lastname = details.lastname;

    function getFullName() {
        return firstname + ' ' + lastname;
    }

    return {
        firstname: firstname,
        lastname: lastname,
        getFullName: getFullName
    }

}

// Creating an instance using Crockford Classless
var person3 = PersonB({firstname: 'Max', lastname: 'Power'}),
    person4 = new PersonB({firstname: 'Something', lastname: 'Witty'});

person3.getFullName(); // -> "Max Power"
person4.getFullName(); // -> "Something Witty"
```

Despite the advantages of "Crockford Classless", the pattern is almost universally despised with the main reason being that the methods are recreated each time. Seasoned programmers assure me that this is a waste of memory and I'm hard-pressed to deny them (they are correct, after all). Douglas Crockford defends the pattern saying that memory is so cheap these days and all devices have so much that worrying about the memory is a waste of time (something far more valuable).

My question is: **how much more expensive is the the classless pattern compared to the pseudo-classical?** How much more memory would I comsume if I created 10, 100 or 1000 instances of `PersonB` instead of `PersonA`? Does the number of methods created significantly affect the results? I see a lot of results on Google that say this is the case, but no-one seems to be able to say how severe (or trivial) the difference is.

Comment: *"Despite the advantages of "Crockford Classless", the pattern is almost universally despised with the main reason being that the methods are recreated each time."* That's far too subjective (and in my view inaccurate).

Comment: *"My question is: how much more expensive is the the classless pattern compared to the pseudo-classical?"* **Test it.** Measure it. On your favorite JavaScript engine -- or on several of them. Chrome's dev tools give you an *incredible* ability to measure real-world impact on V8. Of course, that tells you little-to-nothing about SpiderMonkey. Or the latest JScript.

Comment: Have you tried to measure it yourself ? Just create a few million instance of your Crockford Classless objects and compared it against the prototypal equivalent.

Comment: I think this is a highly subjective issue, as perhaps demonstrated by the fact that the seasoned developers you have spoken to disagree with Crockford, himself a seasoned (to say the least) developer. My guess is it largely depends on implementation, perhaps someone else can provide an answer.

Comment: FWIW, I don't recall where, but a V8 engineer told me that V8 will reuse the function code and that he "figured" most other advanced engines would. It obviously still has to create a separate `Function` object, but we create objects all the time. What real-world scenario do you envision with millions and millions of long-lived instances where it would matter? Memory impact wouldn't be my first argument against Crockford's pattern, or my second, not in 2015. (I don't like the pattern, but my reasons for that, like his for liking it, are subjective.)

Comment: I don't know about "Crockford Classless" but Factory patterns are actually very common. You don't really need closures for them to work, just if you need privacy.

Answer (score 0):

Actually that is quite easy to calculate. A JavaScript object is basically a Hash-Table. Every entry is a tuple of ist name and its value.
So when you use the "Crockford Classless" style and have an object/class like your PersonB, then you have 3 entries . While you only have two entries in PersonA variant.

Now lets assume a real world example would have perhaps 12 functions, the data is not important as it is the same in both variants.

Now while PersonA would need space for two tuples (the variables), lets assume key and value need the same space (they are actually only pointers), PersonA objects would need 4 pointers, and has the size "4". (Multiply with the size of your pointers, e.g. 4 bytes or 8 bytes to get the real object size, and add the size of an empty JavaScript object)

Now on the other hand the PersonB objects all need 4 pointers for the data and in my example with 12 functions 24 pointers for those plus the memory for the compiled functions themselves.

So memory consumption is something like **4 units versus 28 units**, a factor of **seven**.

In the end it comes down where your code is running and how it is stored. Consider that every JSON object likely becomes bigger etc. Consider mobile phones etc.

Comment: There are several flaws in this analysis (not least that 4 vs. 28 is a factor of 7, not 3), which reveals the issue with doing this kind of naive analysis in the absense of a real engine to refer to. The most major issue above is that JavaScript objects may be "Hash-Table"s (more property, property bags) *conceptually*, but that's not how modern JavaScript engines implement them.

Comment: V8, for instance, generates classes on-the-fly to which all `PersonB` instances would initially belong (creating subclasses if you add properties later), making it *dramatically* more efficient than your description suggests. Other modern engines do similar things. This is why when you use `delete` on an object, its performance plummets on V8 (and some others): A *removed* property can't be efficiently represented using a subclass, and so at that point, V8 gives up and converts the object into a property bag (most likely a hashtable), with the consequent property lookup time impact.